# change the path of asset files in jest

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

So I want to run an e2e test using jest. I'm using nx monorepo architecture, and I have all my assets in a library folder and also nestjs microservices for my backend. I have all my proto files for my microservices in the library, and when I want to load them in my microservices, I do it like this :

```
protoPath: join(__dirname, 'assets-shared/job.proto'),
```

and in my workspace.json in my build i change the assets-shared like this:

```
"targets": {
    "build": {
      "options": {
        "assets": [
          {
            "input": "libs/backend/shared/src/lib/assets",
            "glob": "**/*",
            "output": "assets-shared"
          }
        ]
      },
```

all is good, but when I run the test and when it wants to import and give value to it, it doesn't change it, and I have this error which is trying in its folder and not the library folder

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/dev/Project/apps/backend/api/src/modules/product/assets-shared/job.proto'
```

I tried the moduleNameMapper to give the libs folder to it manually but no avail.

```
 moduleNameMapper: {
  '^.+\\.(proto)$': 
  '<rootDir>/libs/backend/shared/src/lib/assets/$1',
  // '^assets-shared(.*)': '/libs/backend/shared/src/lib/assets/$1',
},
```

non of these two worked

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered publishing the libraries to a private npm repository or something like [artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/npm+Registry) e.g. @my-company/assets

The approach you are trying may work locally, but for a ci/cd pipeline it would be much better to have a versioned artifact in npm or artifactory

Comment: i dont have any problem, cicd wise and the project works ok, just for the integration and e2e test i have this problem

Comment: have you tried creating a jest.config.js and updating the path mapping ?https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/paths-mapping/

Comment: yes, as you can see i mentioned it in the question. i could spy on the path. join method and mock the return value to my desired output but that messes up the package imports of nest itself